# Make application always on visible workspace by default?

Tags: compiz, window-manager, workspaces

I want my calculator to always appear on the visible workspace.  Right now, I have to right click its title bar every time I open it and check the option, but I know earlier versions of Compiz allowed me to make this automatic for every instance of specified programs.  Is there still a way to do this, and if so, how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` if you haven't already.
2. Open *CompizConfig Settings Manager* and enable the *Window Rules* plugin:

   [image]
3. In the *Window Rules* plugin, enter `class=Gcalctool` (If you are using a different calculator find out the class name by clicking the + button and then using the *Grab* feature).

   [image]
4. Your calculator should now be visible on every workspace:

   [image]

Comment: Is there an alternative way? It looks like 'compizconfig-settings-manager' does not play well with unity in 12.04...

Comment: This works with Unity in 13.04, although you have to install `compiz-plugins` for Window Rules to show up.

Comment: There is no Window Ruler on CompizConfig Settings Manager 0.9.12.2

Comment: @SRachamim You will need to install the plugins to have access to it: `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`

Comment: Someway to do this via command line?