# How to prevent an "always on top" application from usurping focus every time the workspace is switched

Tags: workspaces, bug-reporting

This is perhaps more suitable for [Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) as a feature request or a candidate for [bug reporting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), but, for now, I'll post it here:

When telling an application to be both

- **`always on visible workspace`** and
- **`always on top`**

this works, BUT, when switching workspaces, said application is *not only* **`always on top`** but also "*always **in focus** by default*" in all workspaces.

In other words, it ( Compiz ? Unity ? ) does ***not*** remember being "blurred" (ie, having lost focus to some other application) in a given workspace, but rather reliably (and reproducibly) forgets all about it, as soon as switching to another workspace and then switching back again.

This is not sth I'd want to use every day, but right now I was wanting to have a long-ish Video in VLC running as a "Picture-in-Picture"-type thing which I'd pause and ignore and then run a bit more etc, whilst frequently switching workspaces; basically keeping said application **in the background** (somewhere on my large screen), **but** still visible, ie, "**on top**".

Comment: I just noticed this irritation, it should be fixed. But it's more general than that - any window with "always on top" grabs focus when shifting into a workspace (regardless of always on visible workspace.) That's super irritating.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that this is not only happening in my setup. What is surprising to me is that I'm the first one to report this. I'm sure that I'm not the bilingual who uses Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

This is *preliminary:*

[Make application always on visible workspace by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37129/make-application-always-on-visible-workspace-by-default) uses **CCSM** and the **Window Rules** plugin, which comes with an option of "***no-focus***". So I guess that could pass as an acceptable, though sub-ideal work-around.

Why sub-ideal? Because a) it requires CCSM ('nuf said) and b) would require setting up a rule, rather than having c) this "bug" fixed...