# Enable a window without titlebar in all workspaces

Tags: gtk, workspaces, window

I have a window (Google Hangouts App, to be precise) that I want to show up on all my workspaces. However, the window dosen't have a titlebar, so I can't right-click it and untick `Only on this workspace`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alt + right click` was a good hint, but didn't work for me, after trying a lot I've realized the `windows key + right click` brings up the title bar menu in my case (Ubuntu 18.04, Gnome 3.28)

Answer (score 2):

You can access the titlebar menu via alt+right-click.

I've used this trick for the exact same thing you're looking to do, and it keeps hangouts on all workspaces for about a day. The next day I have to do it all over again.

I'm testing the answer in [question 37129](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37129/make-application-always-on-visible-workspace-by-default) with the window name (you can't use the window class), but I don't know if it will work consistently or not yet.

Comment: Alt-space also pops up the titlebar menu.