# Global screen between workspaces/ Automatically switch windows' workspace based on screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, automation

Is it possible to set a global screen that does not change between workspace switching or mimic this?

For example, If I have three screens, is it possible to switch the workspace, and have all items shown on screen 1 automatically switch to the current workspace.

Comment: You could set it individually in items you want to make them visible to all workspaces by right-clicking on title bar and choosing "Always in visible workspace"

Comment: I am aware of this, however it isn't quite what I am looking for,  the use of the primary screen tend to change quite often, and when running applications I would need to always make this check. I thought there may be a better solution I am unaware of.

Comment: I found this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/37129/make-application-always-on-visible-workspace-by-default. Let's try it?